# navbar didnt close when click link ui-bootstrap responsive

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

header.html

```
<div class="header-container" ng-controller="headerCtrl">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" ng-click="isNavCollapsed = !isNavCollapsed">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img ng-src="images/papaya.png" alt="papayastreet.art">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" uib-collapse="isNavCollapsed">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="home">home</a></li>
                <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="apparel">apparel</a></li>
                <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="artworks">artworks</a></li>
                <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="commissionArtworks">commissions artwork</a></li>
                <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="contact">contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

headerCtrl.js

```
    angular.module('app').controller('headerCtrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.isNavCollapsed = true;
});
```

app.js

```
angular
    .module('app',['ui.router','ngAnimate','ui.bootstrap'])
```

i use ui-bootstrap for navbar and i check the tutorial from here https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
after i click the link, navbar didnt closed. how to make  it close when i click the link?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you not included one of required dependency such `ui-bootstrap` or `bootstrap.css` file.

```js
var app = angular.module('app',['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('CollapseDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.isNavCollapsed = true;
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
     <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="CollapseDemoCtrl">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" ng-click="isNavCollapsed = !isNavCollapsed">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand"  ng-click="isNavCollapsed = !isNavCollapsed" href="#">A menu</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" uib-collapse="isNavCollapsed">
        <ul  class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li  ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="home">home</a></li>
            <li  ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="about">about</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry for late reply, i do include the dependency. here i update the desscription

Comment: Do you use `navbar` as a separate template in ui-router?

Comment: ya i place it inside header.html

Comment: so it is no need to add `ng-controller` in `header.html` template. please remove and test again.

Comment: Is  your mean from `link` the `A menu` or `home` and `about`?